# WCF wsdl generation missing WsTrust (RequestSecurityToken)

Tags: wcf, web, wsdl, firewall

We have a problem in integrating a wcf service in a web service firewall.
Because the wsdl of the service does not contain the operations for ws-trust (requestsecuritytoken, ..).

How can I force WCF to include all details in its wsdl?
Or do I have to construct the wsdl myself?

Details:

- Binding: WSFederationHttpBinding
- MessageVersion: Soap12

Comment: Do you use predefined contract or have you created and implemented your own?

Comment: the real service is using my own contract. but the sts is predefined..

Comment: So you have two service endpoints with two different .svc access points? Or does your Service implement both contracts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because WCF produces multiple files by default and that is not always supported by things other than WCF clients.

Try [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/03/16/making-wcf-output-a-single-wsdl-file-for-interop-purposes.aspx) about making WCF producing single wsdl. Maybe it will help.

Comment: yes I saw the references.. We also integrated them.. but still, the sts things are missing..